# In PHP, images pulled from my directory are broken

Tags: php, image, upload, broken-image

I am trying to display images in an "uploads" folder on screen, but I am constantly getting broken image icons. I know that it is reading the directory correctly because I can right click and open image in new tab and it shows up.

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if ($opendir = opendir($dir)) {
     while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== FALSE) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
               echo "<img src='$dir/$files'><br>";
          }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: try to provide full path there instead of `$dir/$files`

Answer (score 0):

You have little mechanical error in your $files variable) Use it like "$file", not "$files" :)

Copy this code and it will work.

```html
<?php
    $dir = "uploads/";

    // Open a directory, and read its contents
    if ($opendir = opendir($dir)) {
         while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== FALSE) {
              if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                   echo "<img src='$dir/$file'><br>";
              }
         }
    }
    ?>
```